# iframe issues: CSS3 transition elements on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, transition, mapbox

I am using this tab switcher for my website together with a custom map by [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/)

**[TabSwitcherCode](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/EJ7ve/)**

MapBox supplies me with this code to embed in my HTML

`<iframe 
width='100%' height='500px' frameBorder='0' src='https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/ionious.gejgm43n/mm/zoompan,zoomwheel,geocoder.html?secure=1#11/35.8679/14.4539'>
</iframe>`

Now what I tried is posting that iframe on line 17 (before the /div) of the TabSwitcher.
This was also pasted in line 21 (before the /div) of the TabSwitcher.

After hitting run the iframe maps appear. However when click-interacting with the second map (the one in line 21) everything acts funny and the style gets messed up!

After a long time debugging I realised that the following CSS transition was the culprit of this behaviour:

```
.tabs {
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
```

}

Without it both maps work fine. But that nice transition is lost...

Has anyone encountered something similar to this? **Note: This only occurs in Chrome**

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I experience a similar issue. When using an iframe on the page together with a transition, strange behaviour occurs, elements  move when the page is loading. Could you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I did not have a lot of time to look into this but perhaps, you can resolve that by using the [MapBox API](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/) and parse the results from JavaScript. The API is currently in a state where you have to get in contact with MapBox though.

This should help you get away from problems related to iframe implementations in browsers.

Regards,
Daniel